# Forced to make intents global when used as custom intents in scenes

Tags: actions-on-google, actions-builder

I'm currently migrating from Dialogflow to Actions Builder, things have gone well so far however after adding custom intents to my scenes the test simulator prompts me with the warning "Intent 'intent_name' is used as an action, but not added as a global event." blocking my ability to test the action until I configure the intent as global.

Since configuring intents as global enables implicit invocation it seems inappropriate to apply it to all intents, especially those which have no business being accessed implicitly.

Has anyone experienced this warning? Any tips to get past this error without configuring the intent as global?

Cheers

---

Additional info on scenes and deep link actions:

On enter -> Welcome intent:

- Enter condition: Call 'Welcome' webhook.
- User intent handling: When 'intent_name' is matched -> call webhook 'intent_name'. No transition, no web based send prompts.

Launch test simulator, try to enable test, get prompted to make 'intent_name' a global event.

Within the intent, 'is this a global event' no is selected as it's mid conversation not suitable for implicit/deep-linked entry. No errors/warnings reported in the sdk for the intent.

---

Additional project info:

Initially created the project last year by using the built in migration tool; migration efforts stalled as the test simulator ran into other issues which eventually resolved themselves https://github.com/actions-on-google/assistant-conversation-nodejs/issues/9

After the above blockage I had continued Dialogflow development, so a new migration was necessary due to significant changes. Rather than use the built in migration tool I chose to delete the previously imported intents & types then manually imported the data using the Gactions CLI tool.

Perhaps it'd be easier to just use a new Google project? I don't see any misconfiguration in the intent nor scene, so perhaps the project is corrupted somehow?

Comment: Can you give more information on your scenes and deep link actions?

Comment: I've provided some additional information in the main text body, the only way past this error I've found is to blanket apply global event 'yes' flag on each custom intent, but this goes against AOG best practices.

Comment: I need more information about your project.

Comment: Added some extra project info, I might just switch google project to skip this error, I can forward the project id to the AOG support email too if you want? Is there any specific info you need?

Comment: What I'd like to see are whether you have any deeplinks setup for your action and where else these intents may be used.

Comment: Aside from the deep links which I've been forced to create to mitigate this test simulator global intent error, the only deep link under the invocation heading is the 'Main invocation' which goes from 'talk to my action' to 'invoke my action' which transitions to a scene within which the first intent webhook is triggered and the custom intent support comes into scope. I basically erased everything to start from scratch & ran into this new test simulator error very early into the actions builder web sdk usage before introducing any advanced deep linking functionality.